# Use a short version of the Chapter title with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

Is there a way to implement a short and long version of a chapter title so to show the short version in the fancyhdr header?

Merci A

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{version 1A}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{this chapter title is way way way and anyway to long}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\chapter[short version]{this chapter title is way way way and anyway to long}`

Comment: Good job a trimming the code down to a MWE!

Comment: merci @samcarter :-), I'm learning fast

Answer (score 1):

In the traditional classes such as `book` `\chapter[Short]{Long}` will use `Short` in the ToC and the header and `Long` in the body of the document. Similarly for `\section` and figure/table captions such as `\caption[Short]{Long}` will use `Short` in the LoF/LoT and `Long` for the figure/table in the body of the document.

In the `memoir` class, which is an extension to the `book, report, article` classes sectional commands, such as `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, can take two optional arguments.

```
\chapter{title}                         % traditional memoir
\chapter[toc-head title]{title}         % traditional memoir
\chapter[toc-title][head-title]{title}  % memoir
```

which gives you the option of different texts in the ToC, header, and body.

Comment: Merci @Peter Wilson